# App run in background to manage touch bar

Tags: swift, xcode, macos, nstouchbar

I am wondering how I would use swift have one app that manages the touch bar while having another app open and being used. For example an ideal scenario is as follows:

1) The user launches touchBar app (that I have made with swift) and the app icon sits in the menu bar (with wifi, battery, time, ect.) And the app changes how the touch bar looks (eg: adds a few buttons). 
2) The user launches another app and is able to use the other app while the touch bar continues to have the buttons and stuff on it.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I saw *this* question earlier today. Why are you asking again?

Comment: They told me to be more specific. This is more specific. I deleted the old one.

Comment: check this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/42953538/3608824